# how to move the application from phone memory to sd card in android

Tags: android

In my application i have setting tab in that i have on button like "move to sdcard" by pressing on it the application should move to phone memory to SD card is it possible from code to move the application.

Comment: You cannot achieve this from code but you can open setting screen with your application like app2sd application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can allow your app to be moved to the SD card by changing the "installLocation" attribute in your manifest file to "preferExternal" or "auto". You can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Then the user can choose to move your app via the Settings app and you don't have to specify it in your own settings tab.